# How to deal with the table notes of a ThreePartTable when they are at the very end of the page?

Tags: tables, threeparttable, threeparttablex, tablenotes

I have a `ThreePartTable` spread in 2 `landscape` pages. I placed the `TableNotes` at the endo of the table (there is a lot of notes). The table ends only with a little of space and this space is not enough for show all of them. How can I solve this and show correctly all the notes inside the document margins?

Note: Change the font size is not an option

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[%
left=3.00cm,
right=2.00cm,
top=3.00cm,
bottom=2.00cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\afterpage{%
\begin{landscape}
\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{TableNotes}
\item Note 1
\item Note 2
\item Note 3
\item Note 4
\item Note 5
\item Note 6
\item Note 7
\item Note 8
\item Note 9
\item Note 10
\item Note 11
\item Note 12
\item Note 13
\item Note 14
\end{TableNotes}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{rX}
\caption{Table Title}\\
\toprule
\textbf{Column 1}&\textbf{Column 2}\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
%
\multicolumn{2}{l}%
{\tablename\ \thetable~--~Continued from previous page}\\
\toprule
\textbf{Column 1}&\textbf{Column 2}\\
\midrule
\endhead
%
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{2}{r}%
{next page...}\\
\endfoot
%
\bottomrule
\insertTableNotes
\endlastfoot
%
Topic 1&\blindtext\\
\\
Topic 2&\blindtext\\
\\
Topic 3&\blindtext\\
\\
Topic 4&\blindtext\\
\\
Topic 5&\blindtext\\
\\
Topic 6&\blindtext\\
\end{tabularx}%
\end{ThreePartTable}%
\end{landscape}%
}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

I should see all the 14 notes

[image]

Comment: try to move beginning of `ThreePartTable` down so, that the "topic 6" will move to the next page or insert notes on each page ...

Comment: @Zarko how can I  move the beginning of `ThreePartTable`? It begins at the beginning of the landscape page

Comment: Do you really need a landscape table? It seems tables notes can't break across pages.

Comment: ups, i overlooked that you are in "landscape" ...

Comment: Don't use threepartable.  You can use \captionof{table}{...} and put the notes into some sort of (customized) itemized list.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Could you show me an example please?

Answer (score 2):

After a good sleep night, I found a solution. Using the `ltablex` package I put the last row into a new page using `\pagebreak`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[%
left=3.00cm,
right=2.00cm,
top=3.00cm,
bottom=2.00cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{ltablex} %<---This
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\afterpage{%
\begin{landscape}
\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{TableNotes}
\item Note 1
\item Note 2
\item Note 3
\item Note 4
\item Note 5
\item Note 6
\item Note 7
\item Note 8
\item Note 9
\item Note 10
\item Note 11
\item Note 12
\item Note 13
\item Note 14
\end{TableNotes}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{rX}
\caption{Table Title}\\
\toprule
\textbf{Column 1}&\textbf{Column 2}\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
%
\multicolumn{2}{l}%
{\tablename\ \thetable~--~Continued from previous page}\\
\toprule
\textbf{Column 1}&\textbf{Column 2}\\
\midrule
\endhead
%
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{2}{r}%
{next page...}\\
\endfoot
%
\bottomrule
\insertTableNotes
\endlastfoot
%
Topic 1&\blindtext\\
\\
Topic 2&\blindtext\\
\\
Topic 3&\blindtext\\
\\
Topic 4&\blindtext\\
\\
Topic 5&\blindtext\\
%
\pagebreak%<---This
%
Topic 6&\blindtext\\
\end{tabularx}%
\end{ThreePartTable}%
\end{landscape}%
}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]